# Can't install Pillow in Windows

Tags: python, github, pip, python-imaging-library

The installation process asks for zlib and I even setup & cloned it from Github. I'm new to all of this.

Error message:

```
C:\Users\GThell\Pillow>pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/GThell/Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from Pillow==3.5.0.dev0)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py develop for Pillow
    Complete output from command c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\GThell\\Pillow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps:
    Single threaded build for windows
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\GThell\Pillow\setup.py", line 778, in <module>
        zip_safe=not debug_build(), )
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 34, in run
        self.install_for_development()
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 119, in install_for_development
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\gthell\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\GThell\Pillow\setup.py", line 549, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\GThell\Pillow\setup.py", line 790, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

Comment: You could use the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution of Python instead? I've saved so much time trying to install packages that are usually a pain to get installed on Windows. After installing Anaconda just do `conda install pillow` and done! You'll probably want to uninstall your current version of Python first though but not necessary.

Comment: I'm new to all of this. I'm teaching myself python so I can learn more about deep learning/ Machine learning and become a data scientist. Thank for recommend me Anaconda.

Comment: If you can find any way to use Linux instead of Windows for Python, do it. Installing and maintaining python on Windows is sheer hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL at bottom of error message says:

> Windows Installation
>   We provide Pillow binaries for Windows compiled for the matrix of supported Pythons in both 32 and 64-bit versions in wheel, egg, and executable installers. These binaries have all of the optional libraries included:
>
> pip install Pillow

I would try that, to avoid dependency problems such as you have run into.

edit: The pillow only support Pillow >= 2.0.0 < 3.5.0 and not 3.6.0

edit: Hopefully this work, I was not able to actually test on Windows.

Comment: I have try that 'pip install Pillow' but it still give me the same error message of zlib:
self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\GThell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-y8vx01vv\Pillow\setup.py", line 521, in build_extensions
        ' using --disable-%s, aborting' % (f, f))
    ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting

Comment: Have you checked your python version for compatibility? "Pillow >= 3.5.0 supports Python versions 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5" (3.6 is not listed, which could be a problem) http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that python is different from one version to another. Mine is 3.6.0. All I need to do is unistall python or just download the 3.5.0? Thank,

Comment: I would probably uninstall the 3.6 because the latest stable release is actually 3.5.2 :)

Answer (score 11):

use:

```
easy_install pillow
```

pip doesn't work somehow

Answer (score 8):

I have recently installed Pillow under Cygwin's Python3.6 and needed following packages:

- `gcc-core`
- `libjpeg-devel`
- `zlib-devel`
- `python3-devel`
- `python3-setuptools` (to run `easy-install-3.6`)

I have also installed `pip` using:

```
easy-install-3.6 install pip
```

Then finally:

```
pip3 install pillow
```

succeeded.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It also worked for me with Python2.7 under Cygwin. Same steps, just install python2-devel and python2-setuptools.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

You may need to substitute `python3` for `py`, `py3` or `python`, depending on your install.

Using plain old `pip install Pillow` doesn't work for me, nor does `easy_install Pillow`, which complains that it cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall.

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install wheel
pip install Pillow
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you're better off using precompiled binaries (wheels) than building from source.

Python 3.6.0 final is due out later this week on [2016-12-23](http://blog.python.org/2016/12/python-360-release-candidate-2-is-now.html) and Pillow does not yet support it. Hopefully it will be supported for the next quarterly release, on 1 January 2017.

However, in the meantime, you can download an unofficial wheel from here, then pip install filename.whl

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing Pillow with its Windows Installer package.
Check https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files, Windows Installer packages are at the bottom of the page.
Worked for me with Python 3.7.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much! I was in an endless loop of "can't install x cause of y, can't install y cause of z, can't install z cause of aa" and this finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, some packages wont work due to framework issues .same can be download and use it via 3rd party site.

[Unofficial python Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)

chose corresponding version download the same.

and then for eg,

```
pip install Downloads\\Pillow.whl
```

now it will install without error