# Reportlab install: need Pillow. Pillow install: need zlib. Zlib install: file not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, zlib

Relevant details:

- Windows 8
- Python 2.7 and 3.7 installed. I'm trying to migrate from 2.7 to 3.7, starting by making sure I have every package I use installed for 3.7
- IDE is PyCharm. I tried installing packages that way, but proxy blah blah connection issues blah blah, gave up on that rabbit hole
- I am installing from CMD, where I also have a proxy issue, so I'm downloading packages and installing from there.
- pip version 19.0.3

  ```
  C:\Users\me\Downloads>py -3 -m pip install zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
  Processing c:\users\me\downloads\zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
      buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\me\
  \AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-itydqf_9\\setup.py'
  ```

  ---

  ```
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-itydqf_9\
  ```

I have tried installing zlib1211 as well. 
I have tried 17 versions of Pillow. 4.0.0, 3.4.2 (succeeded but Reportlab requires 4.0 minimum), 6.1.0, and I've tried .whls and .eggs and such to no avail. I've been to dozens of pages looking to solve each issue I've come across, and I have no more things to try. zlib isn't even in pypi.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zlib](https://www.zlib.net/) isn't a python package, you can't use pip to install it.

you can try [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) or use cygwin

Comment: "The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source." - this is after I followed the link and did an allegedly successful install of zlib.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workable solution. As @Sobhan mentioned, I can't use pip to install zlib. However, once I installed zlib from his link, I still couldn't get Pillow to install, because the headers or libraries couldn't be found for my Pillow install.

[@ash's answer here finally helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188838/cant-install-pillow-in-windows) I apparently needed to use the Pillow .exe to install Pillow instead of banging my head against the wall with pip for that, too. Reportlab then installed via pip without incident.