# Cannot Install Pillow with Python 3.6

Tags: python, windows

I downloaded the Pillow package for my offline computer and tried installing it locally with this command:

```
pip install Pillow-6.2.1.tar.gz
```

But it gives the following error:

*The headers or library files could not be found for zlib*

Then I tried installing it with Python 3.7, 3.8 and it gives the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Pillow in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188838/cant-install-pillow-in-windows)

Comment: Some Python packages require native packages to be installed because they talk to them to invoke their functionality. Pillow lists its external dependencies [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries), and there it states: “_Zlib and libjpeg are required by default._” so make sure that those two packages are installed on your system. Please take a look at [their Windows build instructions](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-on-windows) but keep in mind that “_We don’t recommend trying to build on Windows._”

Answer (score 1):

In windows, some packages wont work due to framework issues .same can be download and use it via 3rd party site.

[Unofficial python Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)

chose corresponding version download the same.

and then for eg,

```
pip install Downloads\\Pillow.whl
```

now it will install without error